# Known issues with Redmine?

Tags: redmine

We are planning to move over our project management to Redmine and also our Git repositories from Github to Redmine. Are there any potential hazards or drawbacks we should consider? We are a growing team. We will be using these across cross functional teams. Members will range from 20 to 60 or more (in all teams).

Comment: Not sure what "move our git repos over" means -- Redmine doesn't host git repos, it just interfaces with existing ones. If you give up Github then you'll need to host your own reops locally, like via Gitosis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only suggest you look at this [list of issues](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/issues) on the Redmine project's site - naturally, they use Redmine to track them.

We have been using Redmine for a year now (although not with git), we have about 15 users, and have not experienced any issues with it.

If you are concerned about stability, it might be an idea to use an older version with no known serious bugs, rather than the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I have customized Redmine for our team here. It is a great piece of Software with some really useful and agile-focused plug-ins. We use Redmine Backlogs, stuff-to-do plugins which are great. I was wondering if anyone was successful in setting multiple repositories in a single project? I know that I can create a sub-project and set up a different repo. But there could be cases where there is a need to have more than one repos in the 'Repository' tab of Redmine(For example code might be in development environment initially and then moved to staging and production and so need for two repos for a project) and also to get the issues associated with the commit messages.  That is one of the drawbacks for some people.

This could get mandatory if you have a pre-commit hook to refer to issue numbers.

Comment: sounds cool, do you have the info anywhere on your setup, I would love to see what you came up with